# Not-nullity requirement or principle

Tags: java, null

I have just read in Effective Java that the fifth principle of the `equals()` method is that all objects must be unequal to `null`. The book goes on to say that some classes written by programmers guard against this using an explicit test for `null`:

```
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if (o == null)
        return false;
    ...
}
```

According to Effective Java, the above not null test is unnecessary. However, my question is, why then do so many programmers test for this not-nullity requirement?

Comment: You can't trust that no-one will ever send in a null object...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that with an `instanceof` test:

```
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if (!(o instanceof MyObject))
        return false;
    ...
}
```

`null` is not instance of anything, so this works.

Comment: definitely better answer +1

Comment: Now that's cool. So obvious that I never was aware of this. +1, I'd +2 if I could.

Comment: Ofcourse, that makes perfect sense. Using the instanceof test, we automatically check at it is not null straight-away in the equals() test.

Answer (score 2):

```
Object firstObject = null;
secondObject.equals(firstObject);
```

how can you prevent this?? if you dont' check null before using it then it will crash. I think you will also need to check the class type like following

```
        if (other == null || other.getClass() != this.getClass()) {
           return false;
        }
```

Comment: Actually, you don't need to test for this. We can use instanceof as that is the recommended method in Effective Java.

Comment: Yes absolutely, Jonas' answer told it clearly. My answer is an alternative if you didn't use instanceof

Answer (score 0):

To prevent a `NullPointerException` when `equals()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

possible reasons to check:

old habits from other languages

not being familiar with the principle you mentioned

libraries which may throw null pointer exceptions ( you can't guarantee that someone else hasn't done something stupid! )

if you have a few nested commands that only need to be evaluated for a non null instance of your object you might want to bypass

Answer (score 0):

There are many practices suggested in industry so to avoid unnecessary checks or pitfalls in code but the fact that mistakes can happen or there can be situations that one cannot control like data coming from some third party system having values missing which one's system is expecting so the checks are required. The world is not perfect !!